# how does model.score(X_test,y_test)'s behave?

Tags: regression

Related to `model.score(X_test,y_test)`:

- Why do we calculate score means `r2score` on `X_test` and `y_test`?
- Should it be between $(y_{pred}, y_{test})$!

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify the language or library you're using.

Assuming it's `sci-kit learn` in `python` then `model.score` automates the prediction of your data using `X_test` and compares it with `Y_test` and by default uses the R-squared metric to so (hence don't need to manually derive `y_pred`).

If you have derived the predictions anyway (e.g. using `model.predict(X_test)`) then you can use the metric directly e.g. `r2_score(y_true, y_pred)`.

Answer (score 0):

You must indeed compute your metric score between your target variable y_test and the output of the model y_pred.

Answer (score 0):

**No** , notice that you're using your model for scoring. The score() method will take in an input X_test, and it's target value Y_test, your model will compute Y_pred for your X_test, and attribute a score , using the optimization function used by your model, to your prediction. **You can't feed 2 target values** to a model, you feed to it **an input** and it gives you a **result**, the score method() does that plus the real target value for evaluation , yes sure metric functions take in **y_pred** and **y_test** but it's built in your model so it does that for you

Answer (score 0):

Sklearn's **model.score(X,y)** calculation is based on co-efficient of determination i.e **R^2**  that takes **model.score= (X_test,y_test)**. The **y_predicted** need not be supplied externally, rather it **calculates** y_predicted **internally** and uses it in the calculations.

This is how scikit-learn calculates model.score(X_test,y_test):

```
u = ((y_test - y_predicted) ** 2).sum()

v = ((y_test - y_test.mean()) ** 2).sum()

score = 1 - (u/v)
```

**This is y_test:**

[image: This is y_test:]

**This is predicted array:**

[image: This is predicted array]

**Score returned by scikit-learn:**

[image: Score returned by sckit-learn]

**Score calculated Manually:**

[image: Score calculated Manually]